# how to add data in the row from arraylist in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, arraylist

i have a database..i am getting my database values in myarraylist..now i want to add this in my datatable column and finally bind it to gridview and show data in webpage..

mycodebehind page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList myArrayList = ConvertDataSetToArrayList();
    // Display each item of ArrayList
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("User Id", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Problem Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Status", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {



    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

public ArrayList ConvertDataSetToArrayList()
{

    string con = " ";
    con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usertable", objsqlconn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
    foreach (DataRow dtRow in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        myArrayList.Add(dtRow);
    }
    objsqlconn.Close();
    return myArrayList;
}
```

i have problem in the for loop ..here how i will add rows and values to the columns from arraylist...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = ((DataRow)myArrayList[i])[0];
        row[1] = ((DataRow)myArrayList[i])[1];
        row[2] = ((DataRow)myArrayList[i])[2];
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

where indexes 0,1,2... can be replaced by column names "User Id", "Problem Name" and "Status"

Comment: i have column named User id,problem name and status..i just want to open a new row and under that row the column will have value from myarralist where i have the values of userid,problem and status from database